# Create table in mysql db using apache drill

Tags: mysql, apache-drill

I tried creating a table in mysql db using apache drill. It throwed an error: schema is immutable. One workaround I figured out was to create a temporary table using CTAS statement. But I want to create a permanent table in mysql using drill. Please help.

Here is my MySQL plugin configuration:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "",
  "enabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drill cannot create tables in MySql.

> Restrictions You can only create new tables in workspaces. You cannot
> create tables using storage plugins, such as Hive and HBase, that do
> not specify a workspace.
>
> You must use a writable (mutable) workspace when creating Drill tables.

Temporary table that you have been able to create was created in file system not in MySql.

> By default, Drill creates temporary tables within the default
> temporary workspace, dfs.tmp. The default temporary workspace must be
> writable, file-based, and point to a location that already exists,
> otherwise temporary table creation fails. You cannot create a
> temporary table outside of the default temporary workspace.

[1] https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/

[2] https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-temporary-table-as-cttas/

Comment: One last thing, can I write a java udf so as to meet my requirement? I saw a section on drill website named "develop custom functions"..

Comment: I don't think so, custom functions are for computations not for creating objects.

Answer (score 0):

Install Drill, if you do not already have it installed.

Copy your database's JDBC driver into the jars/3rdparty directory. (You'll need to do this on every node.)

Restart Drill. See Starting Drill in Distributed Mode.

Add a new storage configuration to Drill through the Web Console. Example configurations for Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL and Postgres are provided below.

https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/

Comment: I already have configured mysql plugin on drill. I need to create a permanent table in mysql using drill.

Comment: As I already posted in the question, I have configured the plugin. I am not able to write to mysql database. It's throwing "schema immutable" error. I need help on that. Please help.!